# How to group rows by the date part of a timestamp column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table having timestamp column :

```
create table histodureeconnexion ( id serial primary key, iduser int, connexion timestamp, deconnexion timestamp, duree_seconde integer );
```

I want to get all rows and the sum of the duree_seconde column based on the date part of the connexion column ; that means I want to sum all the duree_seconde column values for each same day, for example if there are data like this :

[image]

how can I get the sum of each duree_seconde column grouped by the date part of the connexion column ? That is : I want to get something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a window function and in the `PARTITION BY` clause cast the `timestamp` to `date`:

```
SELECT *, SUM(duree_seconde) OVER w
FROM histodureeconnexion
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY connexion::date ORDER BY connexion
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fa6d3f7d2f65d3e13ffe2010723ff337)